# Issue with string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a problem with string in c#. I have following string :

*Here Fonts is the string array contains google fonts name :*

> string fontsLink = `"<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontrequest' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='" + Fonts + "type='text/css' media='all'>";`

this string is rendering wrong in the browser :

> `<link rel="stylesheet" id="fontrequest" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" times+new+roman|offside|dangrek|days+onetype="text/css" media="all">`

The problem is with the href attribute value. How can i solve this ?

Comment: I have already mentioned Fonts in my question

Comment: that does not work anyway, the google server returns "Error (400): Missing font family
The requested font families are not available.
"

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx This will help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concatenation is wrong, the formatting is iffy. To make it clear use string formatting, like this:

```
string link_format = "<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontrequest' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={0}' type='text/css' media='all'>";

string link = String.Format(link_format,Fonts);
```

Comment: thats also wrong, the ' closes the href string

Comment: but now its not identical any more, if the server needs a string ...

Comment: does not matter, the google server returns nothing in any way ...

Answer (score 0):

use HttpUtility.UrlEncode

```
string fontsLink = "<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontrequest' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("family='" + Fonts + "') + "' type='text/css' media='all'>";
```